# WebGL rendering ignoring position?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I've been following the learningwebgl.com and ran into some issues on the [3D part of the tutorial](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=370). As far as I can tell I've done the same code but I just can't get it to work for some reason. Both triangles are rendered but one triangle's color bleeds through the other. [Here is a simplified version](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~kevinosu/chromiumlock/) with only two colors and two triangles. Let me know if there's anything that's wrong with my code. Thanks!

Below is the code where I load data to the shaders.

```
 //initialize buffer objects
triangleVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertexPositionBuffer);
gl.bufferData(
    gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
    new Float32Array([
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
        1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, -1.0, -1.0
    ]),
gl.STATIC_DRAW);
triangleVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
triangleVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = 6;


triangleVertexColorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleVertexColorBuffer);
gl.bufferData(
gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
new Float32Array([
        // front face
        1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
    ]),
gl.STATIC_DRAW);
triangleVertexColorBuffer.itemSize = 4;
triangleVertexColorBuffer.numItems = 6;
```

Comment: Did you enable depth test? `gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST)`

Comment: Wow I can't believe I forgot that, thank you so much! If you want, you can put your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that OP didn't enable depth test. Dont forget to enable it :P.